# How to replace a string in mongodb project statement?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document as folllows:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3bad4a86620ba667d764b7"), 
    "uri" : "http://tao.abcd.com/gcf.rdf#i1566561304546290602", 
    "explanation" : "", 
    "item_uri" : "http://tao.abcd.com/gcf.rdf#i1566561304546290602", 
    "option_list" : [
        {
            "option_id" : "choice_1", 
            "option_data" : "<span id=\"docs-internal-guid-8693eab9-7fff-d11f-e67b-ada502ba626c\"><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 16px; height: 41px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"test\" width=\"16\" height=\"41\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span></span>"
        }, 
        {
            "option_id" : "choice_2", 
            "option_data" : "<span id=\"docs-internal-guid-f1a3c643-7fff-e55a-ce6c-af700f68864e\"><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 27px; height: 41px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"test\" width=\"27\" height=\"41\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span></span>"
        }, 
        {
            "option_id" : "choice_3", 
            "option_data" : "<span id=\"docs-internal-guid-333233b0-7fff-01b5-d5cb-db0b2460dba3\"><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 16px; height: 41px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"test\" width=\"16\" height=\"41\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span></span>"
        }, 
        {
            "option_id" : "choice_4", 
            "option_data" : "<span id=\"docs-internal-guid-a544b768-7fff-1da7-1f32-aadc84061977\"><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 27px; height: 41px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"test\" width=\"27\" height=\"41\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span></span>"
        }
    ], 
    "question_data" : "<span id=\"docs-internal-guid-4f97f287-7fff-aa51-5bed-b2689d548143\"><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\">Let </span><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 42px; height: 26px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"test\" width=\"42\" height=\"26\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\">be vectors of equal magnitude such that the angle between </span><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 74px; height: 26px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" alt=\"test\" width=\"74\" height=\"26\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"></span><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 16px; height: 15px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAPCAYAAADtc08vAAABCElEQVQ4T7XTPygFUBTH8c/zZyOlUAYxGmRRFmG0yKBMT1mNFklZDRKLGI0WizKwmpRdMfk7SKEkkn8d3eH1ejf0cqfb7ZzvOb/fObegylOoMl8OUIs6vOMtFYnYz/KC5YAatKAD9XjBRUpsxyUeSiGlgLh3YprvzjbQn0ABHcAijnKAJsyiD0XcJuAoJrCFTTxXAkTFHuxiDUspqBkL6MU8DnMehGkjWMYYTlNgN+ZwjHU85gDh+HiSEFqjzQZMpfcV7KWpfFSSEO4PYzV1EvoHMYlGbOMOJzjPmdiKmTTCawT0ADG+IexjB/c5QCS0oQuveMJZkhJ7cYWbnxbpz5v9b3/h1518AUgtLxAMvQRzAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\" alt=\"test\" width=\"16\" height=\"15\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\">,</span><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 13px; height: 22px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAAWCAYAAAAb+hYkAAAA9UlEQVQ4T63SvyvFURjH8dfNj0UWpURCZiZ2o8Elg7LcSTZl8j9Isiib/0AxW2Thb9BNKeVHkcmgFD31Vd9u57hf9zrred7P+3ye89R0cGodMLqGzjGXMe9h9+eubBpEXwZ6x0cKqhyv60xh6sc6RnGKm5Q+ZRrGI8bwXBXaQAMLuZAp0yVOcPgX6B5r2MYsNnFVbtBqmkITWzjDIg4w9Bt0jBEs4QsTuEVvDurBK1ZxURTNIDJmTQN4wyQeCigmuYyVnKmOI4wXBdHkGvPlvYu78iAizx32EU+NBjupD26dXmz6NJ7wgs+qG9F22/9ly9taouAbqgYkF8/LU6AAAAAASUVORK5CYII=\" alt=\"test\" width=\"13\" height=\"22\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\">  and </span><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 12px; height: 22px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAWCAYAAAD0OH0aAAAAsElEQVQ4T+3SMQ5BURCF4U+hEomEUAjR2oJEI0JnC7ahU6iswQK0dsAClFqFiBYFNXnJlbzIe0I0Cre9c+bM/GcyPnyZD+t9JRhjkOI4xCb6+8rhrXX+DgFTBKKDBq4B/fyB8JlSFlOcMEE1BFbDJSm4UejeCx3r6GOW5FDBASWc01KMj9TCAuVXkccF7SAoxgS54LhLGqmAPdaILreLFZa4pVHKoxkKtjg+j/eDx3cHDvkXF+m5T/8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=\" alt=\"test\" width=\"12\" height=\"22\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"> is </span><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 16px; height: 21px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAVCAYAAABPPm7SAAABJ0lEQVQ4T7XUvyuFURzH8ZfkRymlDDLIgk02ySIlKUpGI0pMdptMomRgMBFZKIPBIOIPMMhIiGxkwCY6Oup6utfz5Haf6Qyf7/v5fL7f8z1livzKiqxXckAbBlCNF2zhNdf1Xw56sIQRPOAMl5jMAgh/vMY4DmPBDBZQhc8fSCEHrbhAI5757tVJjDGcxcEKutGFJnxgDxM4zwIImVdxjM3oIkB3cu0HUL4ItXhCfwQEXR3uMIbdNAedOEUL7qO4ElcILhbTAEPYRgPeo7gmwmaxlgaYw2h08DOu0NAwhWY8pgFu8Ya+KA638QhTOEjuTrKJFbG4A9MI2csxj5t8i5cEDGID9clxFdraJGAZ7ejNuua5gHAOGfex/h9A1ppfupI/KKmuvgCHKzYWuuA10AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\" alt=\"test\" width=\"16\" height=\"21\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"> and </span><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 86px; height: 26px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFYAAAAaCAYAAAAtzKvgAAAFKElEQVRoQ+2ZBcglZRSGn7W7Fbs7UWzF7kSwMFYUURRbsbATMXDtBkVRDLC7A1nbXRsDUezuVp6fd5a7s3PnzoX9uRe5Hwxz/5kvzvee97znfPOPYNCGBYERwzLrYFJagZ0E8KpqfwP/9hFe2j1pjT3aqs09awWwUwAbA5tVWPIrcBfwVM+snHDh5YFdgGnb2PQecB3wTa9sLoD1Pnuusi16/oteGlkBzvTAPDWs/QX4GPiz18D2av3/7bqD5DVMru1HYE2giwELRX6e77PE2cgV/Qis2X5V4AzgIeDMYQB2cmBn4D7gq0ZIddmpH4F1C3MADwMnA7d1uacm3ZdOpXMgcG+TAd326Vdgtwio2wMfdrupBv3dt+C+C/zeoH/XXdoBa304A/BXru86hGNRrnl3jOH8M/AHYGk0NfAj8FvY+A/wacuc6qr9psqzY4FZgZENZMA1Z8uaxdo/ANbf5TZZ1nF/AvplOrj2dPntHJZr2l9u2jl31tMpP8HQIWvezGdZOtTKwPr34tE4a0CBWQS4Cfiojds0dm1gGeAzYL4knxuBt4D1gD2Aa5KMdsvm9soG1LsVgCWzmQUB340CrupAFR3o2ksBXwMLAItm3AsVY2cCVgOOBm4FLo4tu4YQOmQV4HbgmYrxcwIHA+sDxwCPZ7/aenNwGjqhloH1RLM38Chwdww+CjgbeLXNJjcCtgYuDPguvHkMeAPYBLgaOACQqSvHMJ/LDP/eMZt5FnCTGioA73QA1jmKtT0QHAGsA6idb1aM1RE68DVgw+xTp54Q6fH56bFXRpbbwiGd5HkbuCfjjC6j7NsqxupNk4X0NhN7nzFlj5NUhZYLnQjcADyYUJYNPj8IUEJOArYBTomHfe+paR9gGuAs4BXgikTI8QFrzbCoHbZGkpXDJcATCeXjgJkByeDaVc1qQKYKjo6V4RfFEbLQUNdJRmu5TQkYYWvku4oVxaWpMN5v7dzK2LXiLY0VpCZNcBwnWGrmLFlIoHSO7aUYKbNsVybja5DfJgTezXq+V4uNjOvjiDobjIwVgcMiMQJyAfA0cH7NQOVFh/qtwSYG+4UgstU5OjWj1OiTPM5ndI/XWoHdAdgfODxgFB0VbCcpN9ks2z7PXe9vCpwXxriYYTc6BlwLrB7nySzD/rIwZ8skH7VVUNTNl2t2Z3QpF0rFOUkc2wYcWfdAm7Ha/CRwWjRW9nnJTuVqu+h0p483WyWPqLlGxwStDOyRwKHxuu88/ZjNi+zZOoHhLAivA+cm6alxPpdFbtpE5XzLpSLwb2VBtrrBWwCTn+wxae6e9+qkjhqnWSXLDWPDV+fIsCWir1YHSonarpSV2waRDrVZvbX/XMCdySfOt25NPinmk4Ta6FqVktMK7LJhm7rxXPRtDOBVNdhyTN2UhfenAlgJMExOTVYVQPXKsJUZAm6NKtvuAHTkvtFX13Gs8mA/bWh3KiqixWTr2uYAk6CyJIPN1lWsU7qUrUNSHxsZRtXlqWt1un10al3bKbY91iaax6sKZI5Cbk1mqWWyUiurRLxYtChvrAkNeUslGSBbLb0sXbxbqikpvlcLxwLfp1bVGf4WHE9c8wMv1iSfYm0TpJe1sU7QFkPTecbVkxVM9zuE9pkTtEdZUc50lo70d11zzT0By0kjo7L168mrw9569lpyGGH+U8Bc9MEA2InjC6PR5PxJSlMPFAPGTgRslTEPUJ7KHqmbbyAF3aGtFHhIMAf5TaFtGwDbHbCNew+AbQxVdx3/A9Q9JCoP2OqbAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\" alt=\"test\" width=\"86\" height=\"26\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span><span style=\"font-size: 12pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\">.Then the minimum value of </span></span><span id=\"docs-internal-guid-4602c074-7fff-c05b-9a44-7376f12df7b0\"><span style=\"font-size: 18.3333pt; font-family: \"Bookman Old Style\", serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: transparent; font-variant-numeric: normal; font-variant-east-asian: normal; vertical-align: baseline;\"><span style=\"font-size:0.6em;vertical-align:sub;\"><span style=\"border: none; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 147px; height: 21px\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJMAAAAVCAYAAABCDNzQAAAH2UlEQVRoQ+3aBYhtyxGF4f/F3ZUIcSVK3N2Ju7u7C/EQd3d3d3dPiLu7u7vxPXqH/U6OzBsGch+cguHeu3d376rqVatW99z92to2A3uUgf32aJ3tMtsMtAXTFgR7loEtmHafykNXZ6qOVx2i+l710erfu1/yoD1zC6bd79+9KoB6e3WC6ubVo6rX737JfXLm7asvVe/YVCgHNTDxd1+o/HNXz6kuV325OlL1qur31RU3QGJfiWGnyP1M9ZrqwdXf101aBaaDVwdbMXmn78z/14qPawvsHzuNqDpqdZ7qDTuYIy7fsP4i+Lw75Hi36N98ns+sAu6rqyNWl67+Vp2qemn1rOoJG/y79hi7KXb5k+tVMayLb3onnmUxrott0f3DjDz8dVPeF8HE+ctWN6wOW72vetAsqeevblcdofp5dafqJ+Mjp6seWv2mOlz12up5Cw5Y/1bjGzb0HtWHqydXnxqbsWoDT1zdpbrlhqCOVT26OsbY8JsMmjbtJNX9x3Mt6p7Vp8d6cnGf6mTVcauPVA+r/rDwvcNX366eX2l1h6quU52rumn1pw3+aYNXq/68ZtzZqnuPtX9aiWHazBMOllBccsVnuWNifubwmZ9fre4++44C8P6fY80/VqcYebhr9bPZWHssX6ev3lT9erT1y1enqV43xk7f/p/T3DWrMw8HTEBvT6oeU6koybrwqEYVqCKvNFjMuGuND9xxPHvkzLmjVC8cIKQvVPTjqw+NAFU58K6ynYBJ4C+qLlH9sPr4+I7WI/FPH4D8RnXVAd4rVO8cINWuFASgP3Yk+bcLDp2x+mB14+rkg50U0H2rj22q3qGp1oHpLNUtRtFNOQP881ZnqN5YXbASAx/kWnxfr544mJHGOV912+rKM5+uV12lOuZY/xPVI8ZeIYbJFP1xBoNitguM/CECrPe4QQDy+9xp0pyZVBiWUG1vG9VLE/y4+soI4uHVS8ZkFfyu6n5DnHn+liFCUSMwqm5mc7DKzaqzzioAEAXz2RG0itktmCRckJiST0zSVTKWvPOoNBuAFfj4nhnYaAKAtZHfrE5ZfWfGCJNf1xh6CZC+Px7aiOtWgLBWV+wATC8f4AZ8G3fxEQOWf1n1qwooGFAoUM/E5e90m1xjtEuOPTFW2zxp9d1KAWEhrIt9rz9Oo/PcYzHFbV/tEcNqvxsAPufII021v83BJBGvqCTLEXdu2EggKgqA2NFmvf9Sox0CIjo0jvqf7PgVnfHeCp1OhkE811YWGcAY7HfrBV/m/3zq2PwpsUSwhNqIRQMy1Ky6Jr0CQFcf/gKQ4732gJHFsAwYDxjvgG0yzKDtkQGfXPiwlniiNTFo20+Zvf/FiJkGm5suoEXaBy2QKVJgwPSkhc6Cmfmt/WHZZQZkOsMzqhuNolocd46RB4eNb42XcPDm6m6DuQ8wZw4mmgcSIdwGT4aB3KWoGNX9gvHiyMNxwdNYqJFuABYUC8UqFk2eerQzbRB7TSZwmzyn2LmDqskPwxrGzcFl7Ulg0gt8RPHzMXo/81xLlbxJ19xhsKVWAEz0Fk2ooLQRgPrRzCE6kshWnTZwMmuSAnz85cKuyMs8z4Bq0yfNhI3nOlFRPXAw/PRcsU1tB1jNZ9amaWk21xOYzJ+ABDD0jBj4OzfvLjoK37cWjb9w4Ofs46Vn2J/mhAPAQg7/tXmQaF9lujcBDsg9+ui7zx4iDEIJdIZibZ5gvjCqj2YAMsFYQysANmCiM6Bdb2eEHDDdoHrlWA81r7JNmkmgKty6GOLzYyFa7IsDJBKARX8w3tFsigWzACDhLie0CZ/oRK1/smOPlmkcFp9MC/J9LLfJNglw+aeV6BSg58/TRpFiXoxIG2pt9szdFiGttdNVJApfaCPzLrREywG/wldMi0Djv6IhGehO69tr7EoW6Ej22d7rREvB5KFeS0hC9AeGc4Qq9nB55T1NocJPO4CgQlU0hDsd6dk2gYbgsOqyCRhNMjhhLuGm7djYd4+qpm12CybzVBvmwGbagdMIIAE3kAOGdoQ1/Vsruc3QduYRpACuwv1bPO6RJlMc2vxDRizaCUGuoLQr2m+TbQLTdP0BLC8eGpO/wH2R4Z/DgVZOD2o5RLi8Kya+YFMFLAfaFFDMDfs66b11hbPA4502CUSfG4crucKk8mYf5XIlmLQE4HE0RcMmTScUG6QdaIcAAP3aob+rJADypw9zQCBzprEmBsBuwAflXxvtAl07+S0ew+e+qgjtcx3gVLExhD09gTGB4i9jIb/+ULGuNbRHBTMdbbUDugT4iE8bQvfN72kIejrOhmk7/NVWJFWb3IkRz0CySqgD8mWqi41CBN657MDuuoO8G/v+AWIHKMyIaYli/ukGiwAHFGAE/mU6VQzix1paNtDKG7a3X64ogFi3OsBd2bJLy+lSTxKXXazZJGO8myfas+lCc/HdlGRzp4u4aW3PrLPuJDfN3+ntsSQbu2zDfN+P782/OWkzc7HpsrlaiVOqwjFmuthddTm7DFw7jUFe2LJLSz769mIM1p4uO1ftn+JSAMC6znxj0nPTBfS6vG7/18BOqGSMAUCnXPSORfeFX+scCPf3H6oQSApHfVpoT+2g9ru5PQ3+QC5G9BK06H/x6uRALvV/G+5uaNK96w47u3JwC6ZdpW07aVX/3mZmm4E9ycCWmfYkjdtFZOA/IEvlJfNElY4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=\" alt=\"test\" width=\"147\" height=\"21\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;\"></img></span></span></span></span>", 
    "question_id" : "BQNazm0Xkv", 
    "response_identifier" : "RESPONSE", 
    "title" : "Q42", 
    "type" : "Single select"
}
```

and I need to produce an output as follows::

```
{ 
    "uri" : "http://tao.abcd.com/gcf.rdf#i1566561304546290602", 
    "gridDetails" : "RESPONSE:choice_1,choice_2,choice_3,choice_4"
}
```

I have produced the output as follows:

```
{ 
    "uri" : "http://tao.abcd.com/gcf.rdf#i1566561304546290602", 
    "gridDetails" : "RESPONSE:,choice_1,choice_2,choice_3,choice_4"
}
```

Now, failing to replace a substring in the final project statement.

Trying to replace ":," with "," in the String "RESPONSE:,choice_1,choice_2,choice_3,choice_4".
but it's always returning the original string. How to replace exactly.

```
db.item.aggregate([
        {
            $match : { uri : "http://tao.abcd.com/gcf.rdf#i1566561304546290602"}
        },
        {
            $unwind : "$option_list"
        }, 
        {$group: {_id: { uri : "$uri", response_identifier : "$response_identifier" }, keys: {$push: "$option_list.option_id"}}},
        {
            $project: {
                keys: {
                    $reduce: {
                        input: "$keys",
                        initialValue: {  $concat : ["$_id.response_identifier", ":" ]},
                        in: {$concat: ["$$value", ",", "$$this"]}
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                 "_id" : false,   
                 uri  : "$_id.uri",
                 gridDetails : (function() { 
                        str = "$keys"; 
                        var replacedString = str.replace("RES","s");
                        return replacedString
                   })()

            }
        }    
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use javascript functions in mongodb aggregation. You have to use  aggregation operators to achieve the same thing with these operators.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "uri": "http://tao.abcd.com/gcf.rdf#i1566561304546290602" }},
  { "$project": {
    "uri": 1,
    "options_list": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "string": {
            "$concat": [
              "$response_identifier",
              ":",
              { "$reduce": {
                "input": "$option_list.option_id",
                "initialValue": "",
                "in": {
                  "$concat": ["$$this", ",", "$$value"]
                }
              }}
            ]
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$substr": [
            "$$string",
            0,
            {
              "$add": [
                { "$strLenCP": "$$string" },
                -1
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q_puoZfv01t)

```
[
  {
    "options_list": "RESPONSE:choice_4,choice_3,choice_2,choice_1",
    "uri": "http://tao.gcf.education/gcf.rdf#i1566561304546290602"
  }
]
```